# Example for continuous function on the metric space R

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

I am looking for an example for a continuous function $f: R \rightarrow R$, with $(R,d)$ the real line with the standard metric, such that there is an open set $V$ but $f(V)$ is not open.

I tried $f(x)=2^x$. I could found a closed set with its image not closed. But I could not for an open set.

So I need some help or hints about that. Thank you.

Comment: $2^x$? what about $x^2$?

Comment: $\sin x$ on the open interval $(0, \pi)$

Comment: I think for $x^2$ every open set will have open image? I am considering this $(a,b)$, $f(a,b)=(a^2,b^2)$

Comment: @Ahmed the image of $(-1, 1)$ under $x^2$ is $[0, 1)$

Comment: @Ahmed what if your open set contains 0?

Comment: ohhhhh yeahh, THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$. Then $f(\mathbb{R})=(0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

A simple example is $f(x) = c$ where $c$ is constant. Then every open set $V \subset \mathbb{R}$ has $f(V)= \{c\}$.

Edit: In general, a continuous function $f$ is an open mapping (that is, whenever $V$ is open, $f(V)$ is open) if and only if it is strictly monotonic.

Comment: I think you also need to assume continuity. A continuous map $f$ is open if and only if it it strictly monotonic.

Comment: @J.Ogden Thank you, edited!